# NSIS unicode cypher plug-in

Tags: plugins, unicode, nsis, encryption-symmetric

Is there a NSIS unicode plug-in for symmetric encryption/decryption available?

I tried [Blowfish](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Blowfish_plug-in) and [NSISCrypt](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsisCrypt_plug-in) with `Unicode true` option.
Blowfish doesn't seem to give any output whatsoever, and NSISCrypt gives some strange (I believe Chinese) characters, and can't even get decryption part to work without unicode enabled.

Any advice?

Comment: There seems to be two blowfish plugins, it would help if you linked to the one you are actually using...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the Unicode versions of the plugins when you are using `Unicode true`. If the plugin does not have a Unicode version then you should ask the plugin author to generate one.

It is also possible to call Ansi plugins from Unicode NSIS if you use the [CallAnsiPlugin plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/CallAnsiPlugin_plug-in):

```
Section

InitPluginsDir ;make sure we have $pluginsdir
File "/ONAME=$pluginsdir\NsisCrypt.dll" "${NSISDIR}\Plugins\x86-ansi\NsisCrypt.dll" ;you must extract the Ansi plugin manually

CallAnsiPlugin::Call "$pluginsdir\NsisCrypt" Hash 2 "Test string" "md5" ; The CallAnsiPlugin::Call parameters are: Dll Function ParameterCount Parameter1..N
Pop $1
DetailPrint MD5=$1


CallAnsiPlugin::Call "$pluginsdir\NsisCrypt" EncryptSymmetric 4 "test string" "3des" "doq5Eh/wmT6vWoVVyRpdPhMD9KNsWa0G" "EkjR1hOing8=" 
Pop $1
DetailPrint 3DES=$1

CallAnsiPlugin::Call "$pluginsdir\NsisCrypt" DecryptSymmetric 4 "$1" "3des" "doq5Eh/wmT6vWoVVyRpdPhMD9KNsWa0G" "EkjR1hOing8=" 
Pop $1
DetailPrint PlainText=$1


SectionEnd
```

Comment: Seems that NsisCrypt still has [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17657241/587318) of acquiring the context. On my test VM this manifested on another administrator account. I had to eventually rebuild NsisCrypt from source with suggested modification. Seems to work now...